# XMLSerializer destroys parts of my file, why?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xml-parsing, xmlserializer

I am just trying to deserialize and then when my dialog closes again serialize a XML file in my WPF app. Well, this works most of the time, but sometimes, some characters in my file are completely lost, they simply disappear, making the file unusable. My code:

```
    public static void WriteXML(MyModel MyModel)
    {            
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {                    
                serializer.Serialize(stream, MyModel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

My XML file looks somewhat like this before and after:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Main>
    <SomeModel>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Af</Name>
      <SomeMonth>February</SomeMonth>
      <Level>10</Level>
      <Out>120</Out>
      <Hyb>true</Hyb>
    </SomeModel>
    <SomeModel>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Alm</Name>
      <SomeMonth>March</SomeMonth>
      <Level>5</Level>
      <Out>90</Out>
      <Hyb>true</Hyb>
    </SomeModel>
  </Main>  
</MainModel>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SomeModel>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Af</Name>
      <SomeMonth>February</SomeMonth>
      <Level>10</Level>
      <Out>120</Out>
      <Hyb>true</Hyb>
    </SomeModel>
    <SomeModel>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Alm</Name>
      <SomeMonth>March</SomeMonth>
      <Level>5</Level>
      <Out>90</Out>
      <Hyb>true</Hyb>
    </SomeModel>
  </Main>  
</MainModel>
```

Comment: Can you dump the `MyModel` class code

Comment: Are you sure you pasted correct Xml for after? Closing </Main> doesn't have a matching start tag.

Comment: Do you know which characters are lost in the process? Apart from the missing opening tag I don't seem to see any changes in the before and after you posted. Could it be you're trying to send invalid XML characters?

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what happened to your XML (other than it's invalid).  You say it's 'somewhat like this' - what it *definitely* looks like would be helpful. I would note that you're using the wrong `FileMode`, so I expect this is part of it, and my guess is that your *actual* XML closes `MainModel` on the first line.

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` has these comments in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise, a new file should be created.

This means that if your file already exists (as it does), then the serialiser will just write to it.  The file *will not be truncated* before writing, so if what you're writing is shorter than what is there, you'll end up with a corrupt output made up of what you've written and what was there before.

What you want is `FileMode.Create`, which has these comments:

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. ... FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.

Note that an existing file *will be truncated*, which will avoid this problem.